# Import Data from .csv file into mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am trying to import data from two columns of a .csv file (time hh:mm, float). I created a database and a table in mysql.

```
import mysql.connector
import csv

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
user= 'xxx',
passwd='xxx',
db='pv_datenbank')

cursor = mydb.cursor()
# get rid of the 'ï»¿' at the beginning of the .csv file
s = open('Sonneneinstrahlung.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
open('Sonneneinstrahlung.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8').write(s)
print(s)

with open('Sonneneinstrahlung.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    sql = """INSERT INTO einstrahlung ('Uhrzeit', 'Einstrahlungsdaten') VALUES   (%s, %s)"""
    for row in csv_reader:
            print(row)
            print(cursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")
            cursor.executemany(sql, csv_reader)
            #cursor.execute(sql, row, multi=True)
            mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

If I run the program with `executemany()`, result is the following:

- ['01:00', '1']
- '-1 was inserted.'

and after this I do get the error code: ***Not all parameters were used*** again.

When I try the same thing with the `execute()` operator, no error is shown, but the data is not inserted in the table of my database.

Here you can see the input data:

[image: input data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executemany` takes a statement and a sequence of sets of parameters.
Try this:

```py
with open('Sonneneinstrahlung.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    sql = """INSERT INTO einstrahlung (Uhrzeit, Einstrahlungsdaten) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
    cursor.executemany(sql, csv_reader)
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: I adapted your solution, but as you can see in my updated post, i am still struggling with it.

Comment: 1. You are not adapting what I suggested (you are still using a for loop). 2. Are you having the same issue? (no error)

Comment: Sorry i didn´t see that the for loop was missing, but unfortunately it still does not work.
If i use your code the error code is 1064 (syntax): "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Uhrzeit], [Einstrahlungsdaten]) VALUES (''01:00'', ''1''),(''02:00'', ''1''),..."

Comment: @Jagi207 I figured. Can you try the solution again? I edited.